# How to persist poco classes generated using EF 4.x POCO Entity Generator for C#

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, data-annotations, poco

I am using `EF 4.x POCO Entity Generator` for `C#` for generating classes from database. I have put some data annotation on some classes and its working fine.

But when i made any change in the database and update the entity model, it removes all the changes in the poco classes (data annotations) because `"EF 4.x POCO Entity Generator for C#"` is persistence ignorant.

But i want to keep my changes. What should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very common problem. What you want is Buddy Classes.

http://hartzer.wordpress.com/2010/01/26/mvc-buddy-class/

Since POCO's are partial classes, you can create "buddy classes" (that persist outside of the EDMX ad regenerated code) for each POCO with Meta Data Annotations.

Comment: @JitendraPancholi, I know it's not the most elegant solution, but It's the best available. I hate being so authoritative about this but I searched for a better answer. As far as I know, this is what MS architects suggest.

Comment: for better solution you should use the view models instead of using the domain models

Comment: Is this a preference aversion or do you have functional limitations that make this unappealing?

Comment: I have created view models now.

Comment: @JitendraPancholi, that IS the right approach. Code First persists best, but View Models should be distinct from DTO's.

Comment: To be clear you should _always_ use view models, unless its a very very small basic app or quick prototype (some argue even then just make your viewmodels, unless you are using scaffolding to create your prototype)

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is to generate your code from the database using the entity framework power tools.

Additional db changes should be done *to your code* first and the use the database migrations feature of entity framework to generate your SQL script to apply to the database using the update-database command in the 'Package Manager Console' of Visual Studio
I go over a similar procedure here at the end on my DEV215 Entity Framewok for Real Web Applications Channel 9 video

http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2012/DEV215

Comment: Can't go with code first, because i already have a database with huge records. :-)

Comment: Why can't you? Code first doesn't mean you have to always push from code. Use the entity framework power tools to _reverse engineer_ your existing database into code, and from that point forward use your code.